# Preserving missing fields when row-wise binding elements of a list in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a named list, and I want to bind its elements. I am a big fan of `data.table::rbindlist()` but it removes NA entries. Is there anyway I can preserve NA entries?

Here's my code:

```
dput(Result)
structure(list(a = c(1L, 3L), b = c(2L, 4L), c = 4L, d = integer(0), 
    e = integer(0), f = integer(0)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f"))
```

Here's what I tried for `data.table`

**Attempt1** : Using `data.table`

```
Result1<-data.table::rbindlist(lapply(Result, as.data.frame),use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE, idcol="Name")
```

However, I lost `d` and `e`.

**Attempt2** : Using `dplyr`

dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(Result, as.data.frame))

Again, I lost  `d` and `e`.

**Expected Output:**

```
Result1
   Name X[[i]]
1:    a      1
2:    a      3
3:    b      2
4:    b      4
5:    c      4
6:    d      NA
7:    e      NA
8:    f      NA
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Result = structure(list(a = c(1L, 3L), b = c(2L, 4L), c = 4L, d = integer(0), 
               e = integer(0), f = integer(0)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", 
                                                           "d", "e", "f"))

Result2 = lapply(Result, function(x){
    if(length(x)==0){NA}else{x}
    })

Result3 = data.table::rbindlist(lapply(Result2, 
        as.data.frame),use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE, idcol="Name")
```

The problem is that `integer(0)` is not `NA`, so you must convert them to `NA` as shown for `Result2`.

**Result:**

```
> Result3
   Name X[[i]]
1:    a      1
2:    a      3
3:    b      2
4:    b      4
5:    c      4
6:    d     NA
7:    e     NA
8:    f     NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace the zero length elements with NA, then use `rbindlist`.

```
Result[!lengths(Result)] <- NA
## or
## is.na(Result) <- !lengths(Result)
rbindlist(lapply(Result, as.data.table), id = "Name")
#    Name V1
# 1:    a  1
# 2:    a  3
# 3:    b  2
# 4:    b  4
# 5:    c  4
# 6:    d NA
# 7:    e NA
# 8:    f NA
```

You could also do this in base R with

```
is.na(Result) <- !lengths(Result)
data.frame(
    Name = rep(names(Result), lengths(Result)),
    V1 = unlist(Result, use.names = FALSE)
)
#   Name V1
# 1    a  1
# 2    a  3
# 3    b  2
# 4    b  4
# 5    c  4
# 6    d NA
# 7    e NA
# 8    f NA
```

Comment: @thelatemail - yep, forgot about that one again!